# How to use ASP.NET button click event in SharePoint Web Part

Tags: 2013, web-part, asp.net

I'm developing Custom search web part.
[image]

In that web Part I'm querying list item on button click event.
so for that I'm using ASP.net button control 
But I don't know how to call click event. Because I never use any asp control before in SharePoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pre-assuming that you are adding this in your user control or visual web part.

You can add button click event in various methods:

## C#

Your HTML part:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" Text="Click here for greeting..." OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" runat="server"/>
```

In code behind file there is one method for click event:

```
protected void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender,
                           EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the button is clicked,


        //You can do your logic here
    }
```

## JavaScript

Your HTML part:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Click here for greeting..." onclientclick="btnOneClick" runat="server"/>
```

Your script code for click event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function btnOneClick()
     {
         var updatedLabel = document.getElementById('<%=inputLbl.ClientID %>');
         updatedLabel.innerHTML = updatedLabel.innerHTML + "1";
         return false;
     }
</script>
```

## JQuery

Your HTML part:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSummary" runat="server" Text="Next" />
```

Your script code for click event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
     $("#<%=btnSummary.ClientID %>").click(function() 
    {
        alert("1");
    });
}
</script>
```